# How to run multiple cucumber scenarios against different configurations with different expected results?

Tags: rest, testing, cucumber

I have a standard set of scenarios (about 100 request messages) that need to run against a service.

I want to run this same set against a variety of configurations with possibly different expected outcomes.

Ideally I would be able to say...

Here's my scenarios and default configuration and default results.

Here are other configurations and different expected results. Best if I only need to specify results that differ from the default.

Can I do this in cucumber without having to repeat the requests for each configuration?

I know I won't get exactly what I want, but any way to approximate this?

Comment: Ideally each configuration is in a different file

Comment: When you mention scenarios in your first sentence are you saying 100 different input messages for a configuration. Is this correct? It seems to be something you can deal with scenario outline. Also what is the programming language?

Comment: Yes.  Java but Ruby Cucumber

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time to see that you are describing a problem Cucumber would be good at supporting.

Behaviour-Driven Development, BDD, is all about communication. Communicating how something should behave in such a way that it is

- Understandable by non techies
- Thought provoking so you explore and find unknown unknowns
- Executable

What you are describing is something I personally would use any testing framework to solve. You wouldn't be using scenarios to discuss a desired behavior for a system. You would use the tool more like a test runner. And using Cucumber like this is possible, but other tooling would solve the problem just as good and with less work.

Comment: That's an good thought.  Maybe it's force fitting a solution to the tool.

You're saying the point of Cucumber is to spell out the details in the test file, not to do something clever like this.

it seems like an unfortunate limitation, because cucumber is so good at telling us about the failure.

Comment: any suggestions about what "test runner" would be good?  

Cucumber is good because it works so well at telling us how the JSON response is different from expected.  But the connection with Ruby makes some aspects difficult

Comment: As a Java dev, I would probably go for JUnit and AssertJ. But you may have other preferences.

Comment: these are not unit tests.  we have JUNIT for unit tests

Comment: The type of test is defined by the scope and purpose of the test. The tool doesn't define what type of tests you are executing. JUnit can be used for acceptance tests, integration tests or unit tests. Or any other test type you are using. The only test type JUnit doesn't support is manual testing.